# What is this box around my image and text?

Tags: microsoft-word

I encountered a word document with a strange property. There is a box (resembling a border) around my image and text. This box is however not a table nor a border. The box expands when the length of my text or size of my image increases. However, I am unable to toggle it on and off. Can anyone else identify this box?

[image]

Here is the box just around text. Right clicking does not reveal anything significant about this property.

[image]

Comment: It looks like a text boundary. [How to show or hide text boundaries in Word?](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/word/945-word-show-hide-text-boundaries.html)

Comment: If this was a test boundary, shouldn't it only be around all the text/images within the document?  This box only seems to be around certain images/text

Comment: Is is a table with just one cell?

Comment: @DavidPostill I checked that. Its not a table with just one cell.

Comment: Can you upload a very small document with this in it (just one page will do) and provide a link?

Comment: What version of Word is this?

Comment: @CharlieRB I am using word 2007 but the document is a Microsoft Office Word 97-2003 Document

Comment: You may want to have a look at [this article](http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ01066_Inserted_images_have_an_unwanted_border_or_lines_on_one_or_more_sides.htm).

Comment: @CharlieRB I believe that this may be the problem I am having

Comment: I have Word 2010, so I was unable to duplicate the problem in order to see if the fix works.  Let me know if it resolves the issue. If so, I will add an answer for it.

Comment: @CharlieRB the box persist after I delete the image (just around the text) so I do not think this was the problem

Comment: If the box remains after you remove the image, what options do you have when you right click the box?

Comment: @CharlieRB right clicking does not reveal anything. I've added a snapshot to the question for your reference